# Sticky block with Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

How can I make an element sticky using Vuetify? In the new Vuetify documentation the right column is what I'd like to achieve. I couldn't find anything similar in examples.

Answer (score 1):

you can do position fixed

`position: fixed;` in css

here is my sample pen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmKYNP

Comment: FYI, `v-list-tile` isn't a valid element (it should be `v-list-item`.

Comment: Kent the link you provided does not contain the solution for asked question

Comment: Fixed != sticky, they behave differently.

If you attempt to use sticky, the v-rows fall apart and dont' respect the width of the sticky element.

Answer (score 0):

Many components there has the fixed prop.

I'm not sure which component you're trying to use but in the Vuetify docs they're using the `v-navigation-drawer` with `fixed` prop:

`<v-navigation-drawer fixed>`

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers